# Getting a field by a string containing it's name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

TL;DR: I have a field named **unit** of type **Unit**, the class **Unit** contains the field **MaxHealth**, i want to get it's value using a string containing "**MaxHealth**"

Hi !

I'm making a game with **Unity 2D** and i want to add some **UI** to the stats system i made, i have containing a **Text** component and a component i created.
It's class contains an object named **Unit**, it contains all the players stats (Health, Damage, Speed).

I have a function named **OnStatChanged**, i want it to get the **new stat** of the player and update it on the UI.

My **Unit** class is like this:

```
protected float maxHealth;
public float MaxHealth {...}

protected float speed;
public float Speed {...}

protected float damage;
public float Damage {...}
```

After searches i made, i tried this:

```
public float something = 5;

private void OnStatChange(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    float extractedFromThis = (float) this.GetType().GetField("something").GetValue(this);
    Debug.Log("Something: " + extractedFromThis);
}
```

And on the console i get `Something: 5`, it works fine to get the value of a field in the same class.

The problem is that when i do

```
public Unit unit;

private void OnStatChange(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    float extractedFromUnit = (float)unit.GetType().GetField("MaxHealth").GetValue(unit);
    Debug.Log("Unit MaxHealth :" + extractedFromUnit);
}
```

I just get an error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

The input i want to get is `Unit MaxHealth: 100`

If you whonder why don't i just do `unit.MaxHealth`, it's because i want to attach this script to 3 Game Objects, everyone displaying one statistic, so i'll add a `SerializeField string stat` and each of the Game Objects will be configured on a different value (MaxHealth, Speed, Damage). And i will get the stat using this string.

Can anybody help me with this ?
Thank you by advance !

Comment: Is `StatChange` an event you made yourself? If so, why not pass the old and new value as event arguments? Then you avoid reflection (`GetType()...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this problem.

Thanks to *Xerillio* comment, i just made custom arguments for the **OnStatChange** events, here is the class:

```
using System;

public class StatChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public float newStat;

    public StatChangeEventArgs(float newStat)
    {
        this.newStat = newStat;
    }
}
```

So i changed the **Unit** class to pass the new stat in the **HealthChangeEvent**:

```
protected float maxHealth;
    public float MaxHealth
    {
        get{...}
        set
        {
            ...
            HealthChangeEvent?.Invoke(this, new StatChangeEventArgs(maxHealth));
        }
    }
```

And i made the same for the other events (**SpeedChangeEvent**, **DamageChangeEvent**, **AttackSpeedChangeEvent**)

And instead of having multiple instances of the **StatTextDisplay** component (one on each text that display a statstic), i added it to the parent GameObject. And here is the new code:

```
using ...

public class StatsTextDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Unit unit;

    [SerializeField] TMP_Text healthDisplay;
    ...

    void Awake()
    {
        unit = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Unit>();

        unit.HealthChangeEvent += OnHealthChange;
        ...
    }

    private void OnHealthChange(object sender, StatChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        healthDisplay.text = args.newStat.ToString();
    }

    private void OnDamageChange(object sender, StatChangeEventArgs args) {...}

    private void OnSpeedChange(object sender, StatChangeEventArgs args) {...}

}
```

I just pass the game object to display the Health in the **HealthDisplay** field, and i make the same for the other fields, each function is listening for the assiociated stat change event, and when it's called i get the new stat from the event args and i change the text.

Thank you for your help !